# Add according elements of lists together

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was an easy way to add together according elements of two lists, so e.g. if I add `1,2,3` and `3,6,9` I want to get `4,8,12` . So basically:

```
result_list[0] = list_1[0] + list_2[0]
```

and so on.
The way I've been doing it is:

```
result_list = [x+y for x,y in zip(list_1, list2)]
```

I was wondering if there already was a function that does that or are least an easier way?

Comment: It's either that, `list(map(lambda x, y: x+y, list1, list2))`, or use `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more functional approach you can use

```
result_list = list(map(sum, zip(list_1, list_2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just use numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(list_1)+np.array(list_2)
a = a.tolist()
```

Hope that's helpful!